# Logstash grok filter config for php monolog multi-line(stacktrace) logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

```
[2018-02-12 09:15:43] development.WARNING: home page  
[2018-02-12 09:15:43] development.INFO: home page  
[2018-02-12 10:22:50] development.WARNING: home page  
[2018-02-12 10:22:50] development.INFO: home page  
[2018-02-12 10:22:50] development.ERROR: Call to undefined function vie() {"exception":"[object](Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined function vie() at /var/www/html/routes/web.php:16 
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(198): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->{closure}()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(172): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runCallable()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))

.....
.....
.....

#45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 /var/www/html/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48{main}
"}
```

Above is my Laravel monolog sample log data. I am using Logstash to read the log data and sent it to Elasticsearch. Below is my logstash.conf file

```
input {
  file {
    path => '/var/www/html/php-app/application/storage/logs/laravel-*.log'
    start_position => 'beginning'
    ignore_older => 0
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{DATA:env}\.%{DATA:severity}: %{DATA:message}at %{DATA:trace}" }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ 'localhost:9200' ]
    index => "laravel-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Above configuration is working for single line log messages. For example below log message

```
[2018-02-12 09:15:43] development.WARNING: home page
```

generates the output as

```
"timestamp": "2018-02-12 10:57:25",
"@timestamp": "2018-02-12T10:57:26.614Z",
"severity": "INFO",
"path": "/var/www/html/php-app/application/storage/logs/laravel-2018-02-12.log",
"message": "[2018-02-12 10:57:25] development.INFO: home page  ",
"env": "development"
```

But for Multiline messages(i.e - message with stacktrace), it generates like below for each line.

```
"@timestamp" => 2018-02-12T10:56:47.785Z,
"path" => "/var/www/html/php-app/application/storage/logs/laravel-2018-02-12.log",
"message" => "#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\\\Http\\\\Request), Object(Closure))",
"tags" => [
    [0] "_grokparsefailure"
],
```

I have tried **multi-line** filter too. Still no success for multi-line error logs. I need a solution which suits for both multi-line and single line error messages.

Please help me in find right grok config which suits for both single line and multi-line error logs .

Comment: You should use the multiline codec on your input, with this configuration : `multiline {
     pattern => "\[[\d]{4}" 
     negate => "true"
     what => "previous"
}`

Comment: @baudsp your suggestion not working for me. Still it splits the logs by line. Any idea on grok filter config.

Comment: There's a problem in your grok pattern: at the end `%{DATA:message}at %{DATA:trace}` the `at` will break on all line that are not an exception.

Comment: You can use more than one pattern in a grok filter. It's a possible solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28453382/6113627

Comment: Thanks @baudsp. Now I am getting response in single object. Multiline filter saved me. And also I removed the at %{DATA:trace}.

Comment: @baudsp How can I make %{DATA:trace} as optional param in message filter which starts with a word 'at'.

Comment: You can use `(|at %{DATA:trace})`, which makes the `at %{DATA}` optional. Note that you can test your grok pattern [here](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result)

Comment: @baudsp Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally! I got the solution for my problem. and posting the logstash config which can be useful for others in future.

```
input {
    file {
        path => '/var/www/html/php-app/application/storage/logs/laravel-*.log'
        start_position => 'beginning'
        ignore_older => 0
        codec => multiline { pattern => "\[[\d]{4}" negate => "true" what => "previous" }
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{DATA:env}\.%{DATA:severity}: %{DATA:message}" }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ 'localhost:9200' ]
        index => "laravel-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

@baudsp Thanks for helping me out to solve this problem.

Comment: To me this grok works till the DATA.SEVERITY part. After that it does not catch anyhing.

Comment: @Borjante Could you please give me the  sample log data you are working on?

Comment: Okay. Let me know what you have changed.

Comment: This is the GROK I ended up using:

\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{DATA:env}\.%{DATA:severity}: %{DATA:key} \{"message":"%{DATA:message}?","code":%{DATA:code}?,"stacktrace":"%{DATA:stacktrace}?"