# Extract timestamp from log message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, filebeat, grok

I am trying to index log files to Elastic search. All the log entries are being indexed into a field named message. @timestamp field shows the time the entry was indexed and not the timestamp from log entry.

I created a ingest pipeline with grok processor to define the pattern of the log entry. I have tried several patterns and am unable to get this working, particularly because i am new to grok.

**Log sample**

```
2019-08-05 00:04:06 info [index.js]: Request: HTTP GET /
2019-08-05 00:04:06 error [error.js]: No authorization token was found
```

**Ingest pipeline with grok & date processor**

```
"description" : "Extracting date from log line"
, "processors": [
{
"grok": {
"field": "message",
"patterns": ["%{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss:logtime} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
},
"date": {
"field": "logtime",
"target_field": "@timestamp",
"formats": ["yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"]
}
}
]
}
```

All i want is the ability to extract the timestamp from the log message and everything else can be ignored or wildcarded or stored in just one variable like message. So essentially indexing the log file should index the timestamp from the log message and rest of the message can stay as text or string in one field, no need to parse rest of the message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745506/logstash-grok-filter-config-for-php-monolog-multi-linestacktrace-logs

Comment: Thanks @SathishkumarRakkiasamy, i should have mentioned that Logstash is not being used. filebeat to ES is what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

use this as `grok` pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

use thes to set the `timestamps` :

```
date{
      match => ["logtime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601"]
      timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
```

you may change the `timezone` to yours

Comment: Works with _simulate API but filebeat is unable to index the log with below error message. 

`[08/15/2019 22:31:27 > 7f74b1: ERR ] 2019-08-15T22:31:27.167Z ERROR pipeline/output.go:121 Failed to publish events: temporary bulk send failure`

In the filebeat elasticsearch output configuration, i have the following config

`output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["host"]
  index: "index-name-%{+yyyy.MM}"
  pipeline: "redate"`

If i remove the pipeline from the config then the logs are getting indexed, if pipeline entry is removed from filebeat config then i get those errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: meant "If i remove the pipeline from the config then the logs are getting indexed, if pipeline entry is r̶e̶m̶o̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ **added to** filebeat config then i get those errors. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I made this below change and the log messages are getting indexed now. Although i do not understand how, appreciate if someone can shed some light on it

I had the pipeline: "pipelinename" setting in *Elasticsearch output section* of the filebeat config file. I moved that line to *filebeat inputs section*  right under file path section, like so

> filebeat.inputs:
>   -type: log
>     paths:
>       - D:\home\site\wwwroot\logs*.log
>     pipeline: "redate"

And the log messages are getting indexed now.