# What is the correct way to have multiple grok patterns in a Logstash filter?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

What is the valid logstash config of these 2 options?

```
else if [pipeline] == "tomcat_all" {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY},%{SPACE}%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}(?:AM|PM)%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:type_log}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}" ]
    match => [ "message", "%{TIME:timestamp}%{SPACE}\|-%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}in%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}" ]

...

else if [pipeline] == "123" {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY},%{SPACE}%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}(?:AM|PM)%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:type_log}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}" ]
  }
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIME:timestamp}%{SPACE}\|-%{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}in%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}" ]
  }
```

Logstash seems to start fine with both configurations and report no errors, but the grok parsing isn't working properly with multiple grok patterns yet.

Comment: The first way is better. It will try the different patterns until a match is found; if no match are found, you'll get an error tag. On the other hand, the second way will try to match two times, potentially succeeding on the first and failing on the second, so you'll have an error tag.

Comment: I believe that your match statements should be enclosed in curly braces: ``match => { "message", ...`` Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Answer (score 6):

In comparison, both will almost perform equally since the default value for [break_on_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-break_on_match) is `true`.

`break_on_match`

- Value type is boolean
- Default value is true

> Break on first match. The first successful match by grok will result in > the filter being finished. If you want grok to try all patterns (maybe  you are parsing different things), then set this to false.

Your first pattern can be further simplified as follows,

```
filter {
   grok {
     match => [ "message", "PATTERN1", "PATTERN2" ]
    }
}
```

Please refer to this answer as well, [Multiple patterns in one log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450501/multiple-patterns-in-one-log)

Comment: You're the man. I didn't notice break_on_match when was trying to match 2 different attributes, each one with one grok expression.